# What would be a JS equivalent of this Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.board').children().eq(i).children().eq(Math.abs(j-6)).html("<div class='black-piece'></div>")
```

The problem deals with a two dimensional array. 
I know the first part is something like:

```
var divs = document.createElement("div");
divs.classname="black-piece"
document.getElementByClassName("board")[0]
```

wondering how I can get the j-6, which is the column aspect in the array and how to input the created div.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/uqLpqwth/)

```
<div class="board">
   <div>
       <div>Inner Child-1.1</div>
      <div>Inner Child-1.2</div>
      <div>Inner Child-1.3</div>
      <div>Inner Child-1.4</div>
      <div>Inner Child-1.5</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div>Inner Child-2.1</div>
      <div>Inner Child-2.2</div>
      <div>Inner Child-2.3</div>
      <div>Inner Child-2.4</div>
      <div>Inner Child-2.5</div>
   </div>
</div>

var board = document.getElementsByClassName("board")[0].children[0].children[1];
board.innerHTML = "<div class='black-piece'>New HTML</div>";
```